# GULP: Concatenate multiple files from different tasks to same final js file

Tags: gulp

I cannot figure out how to output javascript files from different tasks to same file.

Here is the example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');


var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var jquery = require('gulp-jquery');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    var scrptSrc = './src/scripts/*.js',
        scrptDst = './build/scripts';
    return gulp.src(scrptSrc)
        .pipe(concat('final.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(scrptDst))
        ;
});

gulp.task('jquery', function () {
 scrptDst = './build/scripts';
 return gulp.src('./node_modules/gulp-jquery/node_modules/jquery-custom/jquery.2/dist/jquery.js')
 .pipe(concat('final.js'))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(scrptDst))
 });

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', [
    'jquery',
    'scripts'
]);
```

I end up only with the 2 scripts i have in the scripts folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I found is to pass an array:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');


var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var jquery = require('gulp-jquery');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    var scrptSrc = ['./src/scripts/*.js', './node_modules/gulp-jquery/node_modules/jquery-custom/jquery.2/dist/jquery.js'],
        scrptDst = './build/scripts';
    return gulp.src(scrptSrc)
        .pipe(concat('final.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(scrptDst))
        ;
});

gulp.task('jquery', function () {
 scrptDst = './build/scripts';
 return gulp.src('./node_modules/gulp-jquery/node_modules/jquery-custom/jquery.2/dist/jquery.js')
 .pipe(concat('final.js'))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(scrptDst))
 });

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', [
    'scripts'
]);
```